# NSAtributedString font

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

How do I set the font for a NSAtributedString on the iPhone. I found online how to do it for the mac but it is not the same. When I tried to covert it to the iOS platform it didn't work. I need to set the font name and the font size.

```
 NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:26], kCTFontAttributeName,
                                [UIColor blackColor], kCTForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value for `kCTFontAttributeName` must be a `CTFontRef`, not a `UIFont *`.  You can't directly convert a `UIFont` to a `CTFont`.  You should be able to just use `CTFontCreateWithName` to create it.  You will need to use `CFRelease` on it when you are done, to avoid a memory leak.  Check out the [*`CTFont` Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Carbon/Reference/CTFontRef/Reference/reference.html).

Also, the value for `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName` must be a `CGColorRef`, not a `UIColor *`.  You can fix this easily by saying `[UIColor blackColor].CGColor`.

#### UPDATE

If you're using UIKit attributed string support (which was added in iOS 6.0), you can use the `NSFontAttributeName` key with a `UIFont` as the value. You can also use the `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` key with a `UIColor` value.  See [*NSAttributedString UIKit Additions Reference*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Character_Attributes).

Comment: Do you know how I could add line spacing like 2px or 1px in between each line.

Comment: Set the `kCTParagraphStyleAttributeName` attribute to a `CTParagraphStyleRef` that includes a `kCTParagraphStyleSpecifierLineSpacing` specifier.

Answer (score 7):

Check out the code

```
infoString=@"This is an example of Attributed String";

NSMutableAttributedString *attString=[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:infoString];
NSInteger _stringLength=[infoString length];

UIColor *_black=[UIColor blackColor];
UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:30.0f];
[attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:font range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
[attString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:_black range:NSMakeRange(0, _stringLength)];
```

Comment: it doesn't know what NSFontAttributeName and NSForegroundColorAttributeName are. 2 errors...

Comment: check out the example here http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-use-nsattributedstring-in-ios-6.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=twitter&utm_campaign=Feed:+MobileAndSocialNetworkTechnology+(Mobile+and+Social+Network+Technology)